# How to save time in ecore file?

Tags: eclipse, time, timer, emf, ecore

I have a ecore model. In this model, I want to save time in one of the meta attributes of class. In fact, I have a class and a attribute that I want this attribute saves the current time of system.
Can someone help me?
TNX

Comment: Have you tried modifying your generated code?

Comment: no, I wanted to save time in model but now, I think, I have to modify my generated code.

Comment: In fact, working with the autogenerated code could help you to save time. I recommend you to read Eclipse Modeling Framework book wrote by Budinsky and company. It will help you a lot.